# how to style text around the circle easily?

Tags: html, css

well currently I'm converting a PSD file and it has a section like this 
[image: graph with text]
luckily in PSD there is a different layer called graph and when I pull it from there the text content look like this
[image: graph]
is there any easy way to style content like this. I never did this before like this. can anyone please give me a little instruction.

Comment: You could use this example https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/04/02/items-on-circle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you could do this with a grid system. I'm seeing a series of three columns, with some text being left, right, or center aligned.

If you're familiar with using a [css grid](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/), the following image will be familiar to you.

This won't tell you precisely how to code it but it might help you conceptualize the problem in a way that's easier to write in code.[image]